# How rollup merge a third-party dependencies into bundle files

Tags: javascript, rollup, rollupjs

I want to merge the third dependency into the bundle file. According to the configuration of the official website, it does not take effect.
here is my code

rollup.config.js

```js
import resolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
export default {
  input: "index.js",
  output: {
    file: "main.js",
    format: "iife"
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve({ mainFields: ["jsnext", "module", "main"],
   }),
    commonjs({
      include: "node_modules/**"
    })
  ]
};
```

index.js

```js
import { CanvasRoot } from "react-webgl";

const cr = new CanvasRoot();
```

But when I bundle the file, I get thoese information

index.js → main.js...

(!) Unresolved dependencies

https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency

react-webgl (imported by index.js)

(!) Missing global variable name

Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
react-webgl (guessing 'reactWebgl')

Here is the bundle file

```js
(function (reactWebgl) {
    'use strict';

    const cr = new reactWebgl.CanvasRoot();

}(reactWebgl));
```

This has bothered me for two days,any tips wille be appreciated

Comment: did you have any luck? care to share the answer?